# How to nullify all entries except for argmax?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assuming I have a matrix / array / list like `a=[1,2,3,4,5]` and I want to nullify all entries except for the max so it would be `a=[0,0,0,0,5]`.

I'm using `b = [val if idx == np.argmax(a) else 0 for idx,val in enumerate(a)]` but is there a better (and faster) way (especially for more than 1-dim arrays...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `numpy` for an in-place solution. Note that the below method will make *all* matches for the max value equal to 0.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

a[np.where(a != a.max())] = 0

# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 5])
```

For unique maxima, see [@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49412169/9209546).

Answer (score 3):

Rather than masking, you can create an array of zeros and set the right index appropriately?

**1-D (optimised) Solution**

(Setup) Convert `a` to a 1D array: `a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`.

1. To replace *just* one instance of the max

   ```
   b = np.zeros_like(a)
   i = np.argmax(a)
   b[i] = a[i]
   ```
2. To replace all instances of the max

   ```
   b = np.zeros_like(a)
   m = a == a.max()
   b[m] = a[m]
   ```

---

**N-D solution**

```
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randn(5, 5)
```

```
b = np.zeros_like(a)
m = a == a.max(1, keepdims=True)
b[m] = a[m]
```

```
b
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 2.2408932 , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.95008842, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 1.45427351, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 1.49407907, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 2.26975462]])
```

Works for all instances of `max` per row.

Comment: does this work when there are multiple instances of the max?

Comment: Actually I'm interested in both cases - both for a unique max and for several maxima

Comment: @Ev.Kounis To get all indices of max, you would have to do something like `inds = np.argwhere(a == np.amax(a))`, then iterate through inds to change all occurrences.

Comment: @CIsForCookies Done

Comment: Instead of `a == a.max(1)[:, None]` a more extensible method is `a == a.max(1, keepdims = True)`